# Recovering Stack Overflow for forgotten associated e-mail address

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I forgot my stack overflow account, so I create new account just to ask how I can recover or merge my old account. My old account is https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835858/sri
My new account is https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896902/phpdeveloper.

Any suggestion? How can I merge or recover my old account?

Answer (score 2):

First give the recovery tool a go: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery.

After that, check out the [user merge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) help page.

You can also [contact us directly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/other) with details about your two accounts so that we can verify they're both yours, but it goes faster and easier if you try the above two steps first. We're going to ask you all the same things anyway. :)